# navigation.navigate() from @react-navigation/native refreshes page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I am using `useNavigation()` from `@react-navigation/native`
My code would be like
`const navigation = useNavigation();`
`navigation.navigate('Home');`

And the weird thing is navigate() refreshes the page in the second use.
For example, I use `navigation.navigate('SomeRandomPage');` from Home and when I use
`navigation.navigate('Home');` again to go back to Home, it refreshes the page instead of navigate to that page smoothly.

One more funny thing is that this is happening only on IOS 16.4+ version

Any similar experience?

I want `navigation.navigate('Home');` to work smoothly instead of refreshing page on. IOS 16.4+ version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7utQW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the push method from navigation.

```
navigation.push('Home');
```

It will add the new "Home" screen to the stack.